# Image loading is intermittent on Stack Overflow questions

Tags: bug, images

*Imgur* access is blocked by my current firewall. When I include pictures in my Stack Overflow. I use the following code from other non-blocked image posting services:

```
[![image caption][1]][1]
  [1]: https://www.imagehostingwebsite.com/the_image.png
```

This code used to work fine. Lately, one of two things happens, and it's totally random.

1. The image shows up properly
2. The image does not show up at all. Only the caption is shown that links to the image (and no the image link isn't broken).

Why do I get this intermittent behavior? As I visit my Stack Overflow questions throughout the day the image alternates between being there and not being there.

Comment: We'd need access to your network to see what problem you are having.

Comment: As far as I know, SO doesn't do anything fancy for loading images, it's nothing more than `<img src="https://www.imagehostingwebsite.com/the_image.png" alt="image caption">` in the raw HTML sent by the server. So I'd expect any image loading issues to *not* be caused by SO.

Comment: Are you sure that the links in your question are uncahnged. Someone may have edited the question and replaced the links with 'normal' imgur links.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stack Overflow has no influence / effect on images embedded that way. They're simply directly embedded:

[image: placekitten]
Source:

```
[![placekitten][1]][1]  
[1]: https://placekitten.com/100/100
```

Rendered HTML:

```
<a href="https://placekitten.com/100/100">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="placekitten" title="">
</a>
```

Any delay or failure to load will be between the image host and your device.

---

That said,

Please don't use external image hosts. External hosts can go offline, block direct embedding, or could have images expire.
Stack Exchange has a deal with imgur that includes images that never expire, on their own subdomain.
`stack.imgur.com` is the image host that works for most pretty much everyone, unless you have some sort of firewall rule that could do with an exception for a trusted domain.